# fatal error: libmemcached/memcached.h: no such file or directory

Tags: django, memcached

I try to setup a development environment for developing on django itself.

Docs: [Contributing / Running the test suite for the first time](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/contributing/#running-django-s-test-suite-for-the-first-time)

`python -m pip install -r requirements/py3.txt`

It fails:

```
...
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DUSE_ZLIB -I/home/guettli/.virtualenvs/djangodev/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/_pylibmcmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_pylibmcmodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing -std=c99
    In file included from src/_pylibmcmodule.c:34:
    src/_pylibmcmodule.h:42:10: fatal error: libmemcached/memcached.h: no such file or directory
       42 | #include <libmemcached/memcached.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 21):

You need to install the development header files via your OS package manager:

For example on Ubuntu:

`sudo apt install libmemcached-dev`

Answer (score 0):

For m1 mac:

Try install/reinstall

```
brew install libmemcached
```

and then

```
pip install pylibmc
```

If you still face the issue then try:

```
pip install pylibmc --install-option="--with-libmemcached=/usr/local/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.18/"
```

Please note: Change libmemcached path according to your machine and package version for eg in my case path is **/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.18_2/**

Answer (score 0):

Install `libmemcached`:

```
brew install libmemcached
```

now find the path in which libmemcached installed, it'll be something like:
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.18_2`

Now run the following command, replacing with your path:

```
LIBMEMCACHED=/usr/local/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.18_2 pip install pylibmc
```